# Adding ToggleButton in Android project Causes Exception

Tags: android, android-layout

In my Android project ,I was simply trying to add a normal `Button` and a `ToggleButton` so that they would stay horizontally side by side.So,I ensured horizontal orientation and used weightsum and `layout_weight`. But I get the exception in graphical layout:

> Exception raised during rendering: -1

Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log 
and in the graphical layout only the button can be seen.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:weightSum="100"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
 >
 <Button
     android:layout_weight="20"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_weight="80"
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ToggleButton" /></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your logcat exception.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have this exception:

> Exception raised during rendering: -1

Go to your graphical layout and locate the drop down of the API levels, probably you are using the last one 21, and you don´t have it installed, change to other lever according to your app.

[image]

Comment: That actually helped.Thanks a lot.But one thing I dont understand though.Why the code fragment runs in api 2.2 but not in 5.0.1?

Comment: Your aplication will run on all OS versions depending on what do you have configured on your AndroidManifest.xml, This issue in particular is caused because you don´t have the Android SDK 21, go to Windows -> Android SDK Manager and install the SDK :)

Comment: I dont think thats the problem because I have already installed 5.0.1,4.4w and 2.2.Now i see if I set 5.0.1,it causes exception like I mentioned,but if i set 2.2,It says.
Failed to parse file G:\android\appcompat_v7\res\drawable\abc_edit_text_material.xml

Answer (score 0):

I tried your layout and I don't get any exception. Tried to improve it and finally came with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:text="Button" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="ToggleButton" />
```

Could you try it and check if it still crashes?

Comment: I tried in your way and it worked.Actually I never noticed that  api was 21 in my graphical layout but my avd was 2.2.In 2.2,your code runs  perfectly.Thanks